# Is there any way to enable day-related events in dojo's DateTextBox?

Tags: javascript, events, dojo

I'm using dojo's `DateTextBox` with a connected `onChange` event.

There are cases users select the same day as already selected, which unfortunately (but of course logically) doesn't fire an `onChange` event. But I still need to trigger the `onChange`-connected actions regardless of whether the user selected the same value again or did not.

Is there any way to connect events to single/all `DateTextBox` **days** bypassing the `onChange` event of the box? I think the days aren't widgets themselves. An even better option would be some kind of `onSelect` event for `DateTextBox`, which apparently doesn't exist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect to `onChange` event on popup calendar, not `DateTextBox`. The problem is that every time you open calendar `DateTextBox` destroys previously shown instance and creates new instance of `dijit.Calendar` (referenced in `DateTextBox.dropDown` property).

So you need to connect to `DateTextBox.openDropDown()` method to create connect to `DateTextBox.dropDown.onChange()`, i.e. `Calendar.onChange()`:

```
var dateBox = dijit.byId("dateBox");
var eventHandle;

dojo.connect(dateBox, "onChange", function(value) {
    // fires only if clicked date changed
    console.log('onChange');
});

dojo.connect(dateBox, "openDropDown", function() {
    eventHandle = dojo.connect(dateBox.dropDown, "onChange", function(value) {
        // fires every time date is clicked
        console.log(value.toString());
    });
});

dojo.connect(dateBox, "closeDropDown", function() {
    dojo.disconnect(eventHandle);
});
```

See this example in action at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/ua2Gg/).